# Understanding the effect of a sudden cardiac arrest (lethal and/or non-lethal) on the psychological health of family/friends/survivors

Tags: death

Hello Psychology and Neuroscience. I am a resuscitation scientist exploring a largely neglected topic area in our field - the effect of cardiac arrest on the people around the event, mostly the family members of the deceased or survivor. These are sorts of articles that I am finding impactful:

Liu W-M, Forbat L, Anderson K: Death of a close friend: Short and long-term impacts on physical, psychological and social well-being. PLOS ONE. Edited by Papousek I. 2019;April 4;14(4):e0214838.

McLaughlin KA, Greif Green J, Gruber MJ, et al.: Childhood Adversities and First Onset of Psychiatric Disorders in a National Sample of US Adolescents. Archives of General Psychiatry. 2012;November 1;69(11):1151.

If anyone is familiar with this area of study or knows of any seminal articles, please let me know. I'm always looking for collaborators. I am specifically working towards formalizing the care of family members of cardiac arrest victims.

Thank you!